# Getting a warning with getNodes in React Native

Tags: react-native

It is warning today my React Native got updated to 0.62 before i was not getting any of this warning.
Calling `getNode()` on the ref of an Animated component is no longer necessary. You can now directly use the ref instead. This method will be removed in a future release. React Native Fiber Host Component
in SafeView (at withOrientation.js:54)

Comment: I have the same warning, but I don't know what library is causing it. The warning begins like this: Calling `getNode()` on the ref of an Animated component is no longer necessary. You can now directly use the ref instead. This method will be removed in a future release.', 'ReactNativeFiberHostComponent', '\n
SafeView. What library should I update, will someone help?

Comment: This is just a warning. You should update your react native version. Or if you don't want to update then go that class and comment console.warn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `ref.getNode()` in your code, remove `.getNode()` part. If not then the warning is coming from one of the libraries that are not yet updated for react-native 0.62. Give it some time and then update your libraries. In the meantime you can safely disable this warning with `console.ignoredYellowBox = ['Calling getNode()']` statement somewhere in your App.js

Comment: Removing `.getNode()` crashes the app but now i have commented the console.warn. I will try to update libraries in few days hopefully that will work.